# How Would I Convert This GUI Design Into A Website?

Tags: html, user-interface, web, dreamweaver

Sorry, first timer, yup im that guy. but anyway I am in highschool and for my IST (Information Software and Technology) assignment I have to make a website, I based it off my school website, the apple website and some subreddits.

I would appreciate any any feedback to make it better and I would Extra appreciate if you could tell me how to make the design using code, the part im having most trouble with is making the sidebar and menu bar

AND it needs to be in HTML and I'm using Dreamweaver if that helps

Here is the photo

[GUI Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR505.jpg)

Comment: It's only a wireframe, not a complete design. Firstly you have to learn HTML and CSS to create the site structure.

Comment: Aren't you in school to learn? This seems like cheating on a test.

Comment: We havent gone over too much in class, my teacher pretty much just gave the assignment and thats it, I asked her she said it was OK if i did this, Im not asking for a full design, i would be more than grateful if you just gave me a hint on how to do the double menubars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting a horizontal navbar to a vertical navbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297706/connecting-a-horizontal-navbar-to-a-vertical-navbar)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a basic understanding of HTML and CSS. You can use JS if you want. I would recommend using Bootstrap library to help with the design. Dreamweaver won't do you any good. Get a text editor like sublime and learn html and css. Setup your project structure. Load bootstrap into your project. Use the bootstrap grid system for positioning elements and the navbar. Nobody on this site will write the code for you. We will review it and make suggestions, but ultimately the work is on you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use dreamweaver, this is the approach to take:

Open up photoshop, and design your site exactly like your drawing. Export your images (logo, slideshow images, etc) and save them to a folder titled "img".

Open dreamweaver and create a new html site. From there, you can use the WYSIWYG to move around your images and text, and that will give you the html/css you need.

That said, if the course is based entirely on knowing HTML/CSS from scratch...this would be cheating. But if it's just a matter of "make it work", then this should work for you. Good luck!